# How to insert item on every item in an array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this existing array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [userid] => 1
            [user] => John Doe
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [userid] => 2
            [user] => Mae Smith
        )
)
```

I want to insert new item in each array like `[randomNumber] => 50`. So the final output must be like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [userid] => 1
            [user] => John Doe
            [randomNumber] => 25
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [userid] => 2
            [user] => Mae Smith
            [randomNumber] => 50
        )
)
```

I'm using php using for loop to insert the randomNumber every user

```
for($i=0 ; $i<count($users) ; $i++) {
   // insert randomNumber here
   $users[$i] = array('randomNumber' => rand(10,100));
}
```

It doesn't seems to work. What should be the proper way? Thanks

Comment: `$users[$i]['randomNumber'] = rand(10,100)`

Comment: Use object syntax, they are not arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate with a `foreach`, and as `$user` is an **object**, it will be passed to loop by reference:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $user->randomNumber = rand(10,100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have an array of objects rather than arrays...

```
for($i=0 ; $i<count($users) ; $i++) {
    // insert randomNumber here
    $users[$i]->randomNumber = rand(10,100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think foreach function is better for you. and you have array of objects.

```
foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
    $users[$key]->randomNumber = rand(10,100);
}
```